# Using JQuery AJAX and getting XML

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get XML back from a Google Spreadsheet using it's API here:

[Google Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#working_with_cell-based_feeds)

Under the Protocol tab. I'm able to use Postman and get the XML returned but now that I'm trying it using JQuery it doesn't seem to be working. It is succeeding because I've put alerts in the success function and they've shown so the request is successful but every method I've tried of accessing the XML has returned `null` or `undefined`. Here's my AJAX request:

```
var xml1;
$.ajax({type: "GET",
        url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/" + key + "/" + sheetID + "/private/full?min-row=1&min-col=1&max-row=1",
        dataType: "xml",
        contentType: "application/atom+xml",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(result) {xml1 = result;}})
```

I have it inside a `$.when()` and when it's done I alert the value of `xml1` and it's `null` or `undefined`. Am I not accessing the result correctly or is there a different problem here?

Comment: Could you check the exact return string by setting the datatType temporarily to "text"? It may help to debug the situation.

Comment: I just tried it. It didn't show anything in the alert so I assume it was an empty length string.

Comment: Does the same happen if you open the url manually?

Comment: What do you mean by open the url manually? I've tried it with Postman and it works, the url should be correct, I have alerts outside this snippet that show both the key and sheetID.

Comment: Well, try it without the contentType. If it still does not work, look at the developer console in the browser, maybe it can provide you with details

Comment: I got it by adding the extra parameters to my success function. Any pointers on how to access the xml in the jqXHR object?

Answer (score 0):

xml1 should be defined before this function if you want to access it outside of this function.

```
var xml1;
$.ajax({type: "GET",
        url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/" + key + "/" + sheetID + "/private/full?min-row=1&min-col=1&max-row=1",
        dataType: "xml",
        contentType: "application/atom+xml",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(result) {xml1 = result;}
})

console.log(xml1);
```

Could you provide more code? Like where you declare the variable and how you are checking the data?

Comment: Sorry, I have that declared outside of it. I just didn't show that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasn't working is similar to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799398/how-to-use-jqxhr-with-jquery/23117161#23117161).

The reasoning is that you need an access token to perform HTTP Requests to the spreadsheet. I've read that Postman somehow can get past this issue and that's why the same request did not work on the mobile device.